# Which Versions of Windows Server Match the .NET Core Runtime RID's

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, project.json

I am targeting the following runtimes my .NET Core web application in my `project.json` file:

```
"runtimes": {
  "win10-x64": { },
  "win8-x64": { },
  "win7-x64": { }
}
```

Which versions of Windows Server do the above runtime RID's correspond to? The official [documentation](https://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/rid-catalog.html) does not list them. In particular, which RID's should be used to target:

- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows Server 2012
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally each Version of Windows is in line with **one** Windows Server version.

- Windows Vista - Windows Server 2008 - Version 6.0
- Windows 7 - Windows Server 2008 R2 - Version 6.1
- Windows 8 - Windows Server 2012 - Version 6.2
- Windows 8.1 - Windows Server 2012 R2 - Version 6.3
- Windows 10 - Windows Server 2016 - Version 10